# Binding in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

There is a code, the essence of which is as follows: when you click on the "Go" button, a transition to a new page should be made. This page should display an image and text. Text and image are stored in separate folders and marked as Embedded Resource. But the problem is that when you click on the button, it does not display anything on the new page.

'

```
`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using MDivination.ViewModels;

namespace MDivination.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class DivinationResult : ContentPage
    {
       
        public DivinationResult()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new MemViewModel();
            
        }
    }

}
```

`

The page with the binding

'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MDivination.Models" 
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MDivination.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="models:Mem"
             x:Class="MDivination.Views.DivinationResult">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:MemViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        
        <StackLayout>
            
            <Image Source="{Binding  imageSource}" Aspect="AspectFit"  
                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding interpretation}"
                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   TextColor="Purple"/>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>

          
              

</ContentPage>

'
```

The page with ViewModel
'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using MDivination.Models;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using MDivination.Views;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MDivination.ViewModels
{
    public class MemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
       
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
                {
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
                }
        public ICommand DivinationCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand BackCommand { get; set; }
        public INavigation Navigation;

        public Mem Mem { get; set; }
        public MemViewModel()
        {
            Mem=new Mem();
            DivinationCommand = new Command(Divination);
            BackCommand = new Command(Back);
        }
        
        void Divination(object sender)
        {
           
            Navigation.PushAsync(new DivinationResult());
        }
        void Back(object sender)
        {
            Navigation.PopModalAsync();
        }

    }

}
```

'
The Model

```
using MDivination.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MDivination.Models
{
    public class Mem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        
        private int Id { get; set; }
        private ImageSource ImageSource { get; set; }
        private string Interpretation { get; set; }
        private string History { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
        public Mem() { }

        public int id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set
            {
                Random random = new Random();
                id = random.Next(0,2);
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(id));
            }
        }
        public ImageSource imageSource
        {
            get { return imageSource; }
            set {
                var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(MemViewModel)).Assembly;
                imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource($"MDivination.Images.{id}.png"); 
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(imageSource)); }
        }
        public string interpretation
        {
            get { return interpretation; }
            set
            {
                var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(MemViewModel)).Assembly;
                Stream streamInterpretation = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"MDivination.Interpretation.{id}.txt");
                interpretation = new StreamReader(streamInterpretation).ReadToEnd();
               
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(interpretation));
            }
        }
        public string history
        {
            get { return history; }
            set
            {
                var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(MemViewModel)).Assembly;
                Stream streamInterpretation = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"MDivination.History.{id}.txt");
                history = new StreamReader(streamInterpretation).ReadToEnd(); 
                History = history;

                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(History));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is binding to a property `interpretation` on your VM.  But your VM does not have a property named `interpretation`

```
<Label Text="{Binding interpretation}"
```

instead, your VM has a property named `Mem` that has a child property named `interpretation`.  So your binding expression should be

```
<Label Text="{Binding Mem.interpretation}"
```

Comment: Now the application just closes when the button is clicked.

Comment: What's the exception?  None of the properties in `Mem` are initialized to default values and you do not appear to be setting their values anywhere.  And the logic of your `set` is very, very weird.  I suspect that you do not understand how those should work.

Comment: No exceptions, just closed.
What's wrong with set? Perhaps there is a real mistake, because I'm just starting to learn

Comment: and this `get { return interpretation; }` will cause a stack overflow, that is probably why it is crashing

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties

Comment: Thanks I got it. I will sort this out

Comment: Is there an error in calling text and pictures from a file?